# Using Arrays and LED's to represent Piano Scales

Tags: arduino-mega, array

I am trying to use addressable LED's to show various piano scales using the semi notes formula for each scale as an array and an input to indicate the starting note.

```
int MajorScale[] = {2,2,1,2,2,2,1}; //represents the semi notes in a major scale
int t= 8 //represents the led number that represent the first C on the keyboard
```

The following leds should light up -

(8, 8+2, 8+2+2, 8+2+2+1, 8+2+2+1+2, 8+2+2+1+2+2, 8+2+2+1+2+2+2 , 8+2+2+1+2+2+2+1)  // This is first C Major Scale on the Piano

so..
(8,10,12,13,15,17,19) // This is first C Major Scale on the Piano where 8 is the first c

Then light up all the other C Major scales available on the piano limited by the number of keys on the piano in this case 76 keys

As there are 12 notes for each octave , add this to the array

if i take just the C note

8, 8+12, 8+12+12 ,8+12+12+12, 8+12+12+12+12  etc

My code so far just lights up the semitone that i set up in the array

```
enter code here
#include "FastLED.h"
#define DATA_PIN 5
#define NUM_LEDS 76
#define BRIGHTNESS 10
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
int MajorScale[] = {2,2,1,2,2,2,1};
int delayValue = 1000;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); // open the serial port at 9600 bps:
FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
FastLED.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);
FastLED.clear();
}

void loop() {
for(int i = 0; i <=6; i++)
{  
    leds[MajorScale[i]] = CRGB::BlueViolet;  
    FastLED.show();          
     delay(delayValue);

}

FastLED.clear();
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? What is the specific problem, that you have with coding the rest?

Comment: How do i make this happen .. From the initial array {2,2,1,2,2,2,1} to the first set of LED lights (8,10,12,13,15,17,19) . I cannot visualize the formula that adds each element of the array to its next element.  Feels like a running sum with an addition of a constant

Answer (score 1):

Your current code will not show all notes of a scale. Only the notes at 1 and 2 will light up, since you don't sum up the numbers, that you have stored in `MajorScale`. But I think it is not a great idea to sum them up programatically, since this is a constant and you don't win much by representing the data this way. Instead you should directly initiate the `MajorScale` variable with the summed up values:

```
int MajorScale[] = {0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11};
```

Then you can enclose your for loop with another for loop, that adds an offset corresponding to the octave:

```
for(int j=0; j<NUM_LEDS; j+=12){
    for(int i=0; i<=6 && MajorScale[i]+j<NUM_LEDS;i++){
        leds[8+MajorScale[i]+j] = CRGB::BlueViolet;
        FastLED.show();
        delay(delayvalue);
    }
}
```

So we set the LED number `8+MajorScale[i]+j`. 8 for the offset to C, `MajorScale[i]` as the position of the note in the current octave and `j` for the offset of the current octave relative to the C.

Note, that this is not tested in any way.

Comment: A fear you forgot to sum the MajorScale values. e.g.  `leds[MajorScale[ 0 ]+j] ==  leds[MajorScale[ 1 ]+j]` are pointing to the same LED. And must also be an poffset of `6` for each j. IMHO ;-)

Comment: Ah, you are right. I got that mixed in my head. I will change the answer

Comment: As I saw the edit, I realized that I did also a mistake. The idea of modyfing the MajorScale array is better than the offset of 6 (good idea).. I was wrong when I said that each j needs an offset of  6 This first MajorScale starts at LED no 8 but the second scale starts with the next LED; I guess. So if the first C is at LED 8 start with `j=8` and add 0. The next LED is the D -> add 2 then E add 2 then F add 1 ... the next octave j++ the `, 11}` must be removed because j++ jumps to the next octave C where you add 0. and so on. Sorry for this "for each". Party fail ;-)

Comment: The position 11 corresponds to the B, which is still 1 half tone under the next octaves C. After that the number of i doesn't matter anymore, since the inner for loop wil exit. But I guess I should initialize `i` to zero in the for loop.

Comment: If you've seen my last comment. I removed it because it was complete nonsense. You're right the code is correct.

Comment: @chris thanks that worked.  I want this program to light up the LEDs required and then stop. Leave them on. I updated the for loop and when i did that the LED stopped blinking. I added 8 to the for loop    `for(int i=0; i<=6 && MajorScale[i]+j+8<=NUM_LEDS;i++)`  I don't quite know why it worked ?